# Convert from System.Address to Integer in Ada

Tags: memory-management, ada, memory-address

In the example below, I am wondering, why `line 17` does not work, but `line 18`? Can I not convert a `System.Address` directly to an `Integer` (see `line 17`)?

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with System.Storage_Elements;

procedure Main is
   package SSE renames System.Storage_Elements;

   type Integer_Access is access Integer;
   I1_Access : Integer_Access := new Integer'(42);
   I1_Address : System.Address := I1_Access.all'Address;

   function Convert1 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (System.Address, Integer);
   function Convert2 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (System.Address, Integer_Access);
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (SSE.To_Integer (I1_Access'Address)'Img);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (SSE.To_Integer (I1_Access.all'Address)'Img);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (I1_Access.all'Img);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Convert1 (I1_Address)'Img);  --  why does this NOT work?
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Convert2 (I1_Address).all'Img);  --  why does this work?
end Main;
```

**Result**

```
 140734773254664
 140243203260416
 42
-363855872
 42
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I compile your code on this Mac with `-gnatwa` (most warnings) and -gnatl (generate a listing) I get (excerpted)

```
12.    function Convert1 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (System.Address, Integer);
       |
    >>> warning: types for unchecked conversion have different sizes
```

because `Integer` is 32-bits while `System.Address` (and most access types) are 64-bits. Your machine is evidently similar.

So the reason you get a weird 5th output line (I got -490720512, by the way) is that it’s only looking at the bottom 32 bits of the actual address.

You might look at `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` ([ARM 13.7.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-7-2.html)) for the supported way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `package Convert3 is new System.Address_To_Access_Conversions (Integer);` with `Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Convert3.To_Pointer (I1_Address).all'Img);` which worked. Now, it makes also sense, why `Convert1` cannot work.

Answer (score 4):

It does work. Apparently it's doing something other than what you expected.

You can convert a `System.Address` to an `Integer` using `Unchecked_Conversion`, but the result isn't necessarily going to be meaningful. You'll get an integer representing the (probably virtual) address held in the `System.Address` value -- *not* the value of whatever object it points to. And if `System.Address` and `Integer` aren't the same size, the result will be even less meaningful.

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Convert1 (I1_Address)'Img);
```

This prints an `Integer` representation of a memory address. It's not particularly meaningful. (Typically you'd want to see such an address in hexadecimal.)

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Convert2 (I1_Address).all'Img);
```

This prints the `Integer` value, `42`, of the object at the memory location indicated by the value of `I1_Address`. It's just a roundabout way of printing `I1_Access.all`.

Comment: Thanks! So, the correct way to get the value behind a `System.Address` is to convert the `System.Address` to the `Integer` access type and then dereference it – as I am doing it in line 18?

Comment: @user1091344: In this case, you already have an `Integer_Access` value, which you're converting to `System.Address` and back again. But if you have a `System.Address` value from some outside source and you need to access the `Integer` object it points to, then yes, you need to do an `Unchecked_Conversion` to convert it to some `access Integer` type that  you can dereference. (If the `System.Address` value is not valid, this can blow up in your face.) But don't do that unless you actually need to. (There might be a cleaner approach; I've been away from Ada for quite a while.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Using `Unchecked_Conversion` to convert between `System.Address` and access types isn't reliable.  With non-GNAT compilers, an access type could, in some cases, be a "fat" pointer that contains additional data besides an address (e.g. array bounds, accessibility level, stack frame pointer).  `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` is more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to print the value of an image, as in your example, consider using the function `System.Address_Image`. This is not good for pointer arithmetic, but leads to better output (hexadecimal, for instance)